# Modify prestashops search algorithm

Tags: prestashop

I've added some database tables to prestashop 1.5.3 which contain additional product data. Now I'd like to modify the search-alorithm from prestashop to include those tables.

I had guessed that the corresponding code would be found in classes/search.php, but modifing this code does not change anything. I even deleted the whole file and the search function kept working.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction and tell me where I can find prestashops search-code.

Comment: Can you please point us some directions on how to enhance the logic behind default behaviour of search in PS? any links will be highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching code is really in /classes/Search.php. I cannot see why search is still working with this file empty...

Please don't modify core files, you'd rather add your logic in the overriden one :

> /override/classes/Search.php

Comment: Thanks. I'll use the class in the override folder. My problem is solved. I edited the search.php from my backup-folder ;).